# How to access object's member variable's dereferenced value

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, copy-constructor

I am trying to copy an object passed to a copy constructor function. I want to access the dereferenced value of a member variable of the object that is passed to this function but am getting an error "expected unqualified-id before '(' token int *c = new int(other.(*pa));

The class is defined:

```
class Foo {
Public:
   int *a, *b;
   Foo(const Foo &); //copy constructor
}
```

My function is defined:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) {
    int* c = new int(other.(*a));
    int* d = new int(other.(*b));
 }
```

Main is defined:

```
Foo first(1,2);
Foo second(first);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy constructor can look like

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) : a( new int( *other.a ) ), b( new int( *other.b ) )
{
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
   int *a, *b;

   Foo( int x, int y ) : a( new int( x ) ), b( new int( y ) )
   {
   }

   Foo( const Foo &other  ) : a( new int( *other.a ) ), b( new int( *other.b ) )
   {
   }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo first(1,2);
    Foo second(first); 

    std::cout << *first.a << ", " << *first.b << '\n';
    std::cout << *second.a << ", " << *second.b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1, 2
1, 2
```

All other special member functions as for example the destructor I hope you will define yourself.

Comment: Is there a difference between how you have defined your constructor and Foo::Foo(int a, int b) { int *x = new int(a); int *y = new int(b); }

Comment: @Reno Using a initializer list, like Vlad does, is the preferred method to initialize member variables. For pointers the results are identical but for any object that has a constructor the difference can be very different.

Comment: @Reno - A key difference is that Vlad's approach will work (actually initialise `Foo`s members) whereas your approach will not (since it assigns to variables of automatic storage duration that cease to exist when the constructor completes, and not the members of `Foo`).

Comment: @Reno In this constructor Foo::Foo(int a, int b) { int *x = new int(a); int *y = new int(b);  you declare local variables x and y that will not be laive after exiting the constructor.

Comment: OK I understand I shouldn't use new variables x and y, but are we saying I should always use an initializer list rather than say Foo::Foo(int x, int y) { a = new int(x); b = new int(y);}

Comment: @Reno Within the body of the constructor there is used the assignment operator. In general you should prefer to use mem-initializers as I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the values to object members.

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) {
    this->a = new int(other.(*a));
    this->b = new int(other.(*b));
 }
```

Comment: No on several counts. I would fix before it gets downvoted by others. 1: Don't use `this` 2: `*a` the star does not go there (that is d-referencing the local object). 3: Use initializer list. 4: The use of `this` requires a pointer not a dot `this->a`

Comment: Usage of `this.a` and `this.b` are invalid - i.e. the compiler is required to diagnose that usage as an error - since `this` is a pointer, not a reference.